# Why Local Firestore Emulator doesn't react to the trigger?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-tools

I have this block of code in my `/functions/src/index.ts`:

```
export const onAddReviewerSendEmailNotification = functions
    .runWith({
      timeoutSeconds: 15,
    })
    .firestore.document("records/{email}/managedByOthers/{reviewerEmail}")
    .onWrite( (snap, context) => {
      functions.logger.info("something changed!");
      functions.logger.debug(`Running add reviewer trigger for userId: ${context.params.email}, reviewerId: ${context.params.reviewerEmail}`);
    });
```

I compile it using `npm run build` in the `functions` directory. Then I run the emulator using this command:

```
firebase emulators:start --only firestore,storage,functions --import test-data
```

This is what I get:
[image]

I can see emulator UI is running. I go to `firestore` and add a record in this path: `records/{email}/managedByOthers/{reviewerEmail}`. Then I go to emulator's `Logs` section. Nothing has been logged. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the solution after wasting 4 hours on the issue. I replaced

```
"functions": {
      "port": 5001
    },
```

by

```
"functions": {
      "host": "0.0.0.0",
      "port": 5001
    },
```

in the `firebase.json` file. I am able to see the logs now!